# Telegraf logparser giving error. Error parsing log line:: must have one or more fields

Tags: influxdb, telegraf, telegraf-inputs-plugin, telegraf-plugins

Using Log parser input plugin, writing custom logs to influxdb.
Input plugin logparser giving error: Error parsing log line:

> filename.log: must have one or more fields.

This is running telegraf version 1.5.3 and is failing with above error.
I expect telegraf logs to be fine and dump data to influx.

Answer (score 0):

In influxdb, every point(record) is a group of tags and fields. Time is one of the default tags. But you should provide at least one field as part of a point. Your error hints the paoint, that you are trying insert does not have any fields.

Comment: Do I need to add an hint for field. I have added hint for tag but I did not find any hint for field in the documentation. My row doesn't has a timestamp. I am using influx's insert timestamp.